# Can statues being pulled down in #BlackLivesMatter be called 'iconoclasm'?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, neologisms

During the worldwide protests of #BlackLivesMatter, a large number of statues commemorating colonial conquest in the modern era have been pulled down by protesters.

Is it appropriate to call them 'iconoclasts' in the original meaning of the term?

If not, is there a more appropriate term? Or has a new one actually been coined by either protesters or commentators?

Comment: What do you mean by "original meaning"? Merriam-Webster lists [two senses](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iconoclast) of the base word *iconoclast*. Which do you think was the first? Of, if you're not sure which was first, which particular sense are you thinking of? (Per that reference, the original Greek literally meant simply "image destroyer.")

Comment: @Jason Blandford: Given the description of iconoclasts as destroyers of icons, you can see why I thought of the these protesters as iconoclasts in the original meaning. Of course, these are not religious statues; nevertheless, they have been put up for the purposes of commemoration,  that is veneration; so I think this latter sense holds close enough for it to also be meaningful.

Comment: @Jason Blandford: I said in its original meaning simply to distinguish from its contemporary meaning of a rebel of thought.

Answer (score 2):

It's reasonable to equate this action to "iconoclasm".  By most standards the individuals represented are metaphoric icons, and their statues can similarly be considered icons.  And the etymological source of "icon" is "image".  Plus the "clasm" part derives from a Greek term meaning "to break".

Some people will tell you that the terms only apply to religious symbols, but in fact they apply to any object of veneration.

Answer (score -2):

As per M-W:

> *[iconoclast](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iconoclast)*: 1: a person who attacks settled beliefs or institutions; 2: a person who destroys religious images or opposes their veneration

In the context of your question, we need to focus on the first definition, as the statues commemorating colonial conquest in the modern era are not religious images *per se*.

With regard to the first definition, the attacks in question are intellectual attacks, not physical attacks. One can't physically attack a belief or an institution. While one could attack a building associated with an institution, that building is not the underlying institution itself. So I would say, it's not appropriate to consider the protesters pulling down statues *iconoclasts*.

An appropriate term may be **zealot** or **true believer** or **freedom fighter** or **revolutionary**. From M-W:

> **[zealot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zealot)**: a zealous person, especially a fanatical partisan

> **[true believer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/true%20believer)**: a zealous supporter of a particular cause

> **[freedom fighter](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/freedom%20fighter)**: a person who takes part in a resistance movement against an oppressive political or social establishment

> **[revolutionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revolutionary)**: tending to or promoting revolution

You could also simply call the **protestors**. Politicians on the right have called the people pulling down these statues members of a *radical left-wing mob*, *thugs*, and *terrorists*, so the descriptor you choose will depend on your perspective.